# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/net/MediaType in Selenium webDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am getting an error in my code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
}
```

Comment: i am getting the following Exceptions.....

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks perfect.

I think you have missed to add Selenium Server jar

Download the jar from below link and add it your build path -> libraries

http://goo.gl/PJUZfa